# Compare 2 Arrays and if one cell is empty add value to another

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 Arrays:

```
arr1 = [[Name1,date, 10],[Name2,date, 20],[Name3,date,10]]  
arr2 = [[Name1, " "], [Name2, randomtext]]
```

The names in `Arr2` are less then in `Arr1` and not in order.
I want to add `10` to the current value of `arr1` if in `arr2` the second cell is empty and obviously I want to add it to the correct Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume in both solutions that by `'empty'` you actually mean `''`. If this is not the case, then simply replace the latter with the first in both solutions.

### Solution 1:

You can do that with two simple `for` loops:

```js
  const arr1 = [["Name1","date", 10],["Name2","date", 20],["Name3","date",10]]
  const arr2 = [["Name1", ''], ["Name2", "randomtext"]]
  for(let i=0; i<arr1.length;i++){
    for(let j=0; j<arr2.length;j++){
      if(arr1[i][0]==arr2[j][0] && arr2[j][1]==''){
        arr1[i][2] +=10;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(arr1)
```

### Solution 2:

A shorter and more modern approach would be to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
  const arr1 = [["Name1","date", 10],["Name2","date", 20],["Name3","date",10]]
  const arr2 = [["Name1", ''], ["Name2", "randomtext"]]
  arr1.map((r1,i)=>arr2.map(r2=>{if(r1[0]==r2[0] && r2[1]=='') arr1[i][2] +=10}))
  console.log(arr1)
```

For the second solution make sure you have the v8 environment enabled.

Comment: Thank you works perfect. Only thing I had to add was && arr2[i][0] != " " because I have some empty Cells in between.